# How to I display these radio buttons horizontally?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, radio-button, woocommerce

I have the following table for product variations from woocommerce. Does someone have an idea how i can display these horizontally? I've looked through several different forums but so far none of my attempts have worked.
It concerns the woocommerce product variations. They are being displayed as radio buttons instead of as dropdown but I can't seem to align them horizontally.
thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <label for="pa_kit">Kit</label>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                <fieldset> <strong>Kit</strong><br>
                    <div class="wvdrb-one-third"><input type="radio" value="set-20" id="pa_kit"            name="attribute_pa_kit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; set-20</div><div class="wvdrb-two-    thirds"></div><br>
                    <div class="wvdrb-one-third"><input type="radio" value="set-35"     checked="checked" id="pa_kit" name="attribute_pa_kit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; set-    35</div><div class="wvdrb-two-thirds"></div><br>
                    <div class="wvdrb-one-third"><input type="radio" value="set-50" id="pa_kit"     name="attribute_pa_kit"> &nbsp; &nbsp; set-50</div><div class="wvdrb-two-    thirds"></div><br>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this --- Cleaned up a bit.

```html
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_kit">Kit</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <fieldset> <strong>Kit</strong>
          <br>
          <div>
            <div class="wvdrb-one-third">
              <input type="radio" value="set-20" id="pa_kit" name="attribute_pa_kit">set-20&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" value="set-35" checked="checked" id="pa_kit" name="attribute_pa_kit">set-35&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" value="set-50" id="pa_kit" name="attribute_pa_kit">set-50
            </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Jim. Thanks for your quick response. As you say the format of the buttons is messed up. I got the horizontal display to work on chrome check element. The css is correct but for some reason woocommerce adds a </br> after each of the radio buttons, stopping them from displaying inline. Do you have any idea which woocommerce file to modify in order to take away the breaks or some other method to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

the mystery is solved. I had to remove the breaks between the radio buttons. This I did by entering the variations.php file from woocommerce and removing the 
.
Then the css worked and put the buttons inline.

thanks!